# what is causing this surprising array result in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I'm sure this isn't surprising to some out there, but I am getting something very unexpected in the following component:

```
const GameBoard = ({
    moves = [[1,2]]
}:Props) => {

    const [sideLength, setSideLength] = useState(3);


    let rows = Array(sideLength).fill(Array(sideLength).fill(''));
    console.log(rows);
    for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
        const [y,x] = moves[i];
        const mark:Mark = i % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
        rows[y][x] = mark;
    }
    console.log(rows);
    return (
        <div className="game-board">
            { rows.map(row => <Row row={row}/>)};
        </div>
    );
};
```

This component represents a tic tac toe gameboard.  A prop called `moves` should determine where markings are made on the board.  In the following line, I start with a blank board:
`let rows = Array(sideLength).fill(Array(sideLength).fill(''));`
And then I populate the rows with markings based on `moves`.  `[[1,2]]` means that only the first move has been made (X according to the rules), and it was placed one down and 2 over.

I expect the `console.log` after `let rows...` to log:

```
    [ '', '', '']
    ['', '', '']
    ['', '', '']
```

Instead, both this line and the log after the for loop logs the following:
0
:

```
['', '', 'X']
['', '', 'X']
['', '', 'X']
```

So my questions are:

1. why isn't the first log only full of empty strings?
2. why is an entire column of the second log filled instead of just one square ([2,1])?

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bash-shdpoi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When I run `Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(''))`, it does indeed show a 3x3 array of empty strings. I don't see how your code coudl do otherwise (assuming `sideLength` has the value `3`).

Comment: Do you have a link to code sandbox or something similar where we can run your code ourselves?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. sorry, here's the correct link
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bash-shdpoi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I assume you are looking in the browser console. And you expand the output from the first `console.log()` after the whole page loads, right? Apparently the browser updates the object in the console with its current state.

Comment: On a side note, I strongly encourage you to install the React Dev Tools browser plugin. This is incredibly helpful for debugging component state and props. And you shouldn't run afowl of these kind of weird behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re. 1: it actually is! The issue you are probably facing is that you are looking at the console in the browser. There, the content of a printed object may change after the printing to the console. If instead of `console.log(rows)` you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(rows))` you'll see that it actually is what you expected (all empty strings).

Re. 2: This is because you are initializing all three top level array element with the *same* array (it's a reference!). This is even shown in the MDN documentation of the Array.fill method, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#using_fill:

```
// A single object, referenced by each slot of the array:
const arr = Array(3).fill({}); // [{}, {}, {}]
arr[0].hi = "hi";              // [{ hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }]
```

You'll need to create three different arrays to fill the top level array with.

Comment: The documentation wouldn't even need to mention this.